# How to call multiple redirects from one file on server with . htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to permanently redirect about 50 links from one page to another. I was thinking to create a file called 301.html and inside to put redirect codes "Redirect 301 /test/my-post1.html https://test/my-post-2/" and so one. How to call that file "301.html" from .htaccess file?

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /301.html [L,QSA]
```

or with 301.php instead of html?

Comment: A html file will get delivered as html markup by the http server. Why should it interpret it as a configuration file? It won't.

Comment: You want to implement such redirection in your http server's host configuration. That is where it belongs. Why don't you do that?

Comment: We cannot say more here, since you offer far to few details. Try to ask yourself this question: you want to redirect requests. Fine. There are _thousands_ of answers to that here on SO. If all those answers do not help, then _why_ not? Without you telling us we don't know why you can't simply implement such redirections from the examples here on SO and in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want to call file like this using htaccess:

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional information, don't do that here in the comments.

Comment: I will try to explain things in a different wording: rewriting or redirection rules belong in the server configuration. Be it the real host configuration or distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). php and html files are _content_ files, not configuration files. Your rewriting or redirection rules belong into the .htaccess file or, preferably, in the real http server's host configuration, but _not_ in html or php files.

Comment: Is there a pattern in the file names or do you really have to implement 50 explicit, separate redirection rules?

Comment: unfortunately, all redirects are separate no way to create a pattern. I have created this redirects in .htaccess but its a long list and it's not good for .htaccess to have that much code and with time probably I will add more. I thought to load through .htaccess, a file that contains all redirect codes.

Comment: Why should such a list be better in another file? But anyway, that is not possible the way you suggest, so let's just drop it. For really huge lists you can implement a _script_ , for example based on php, which uses a database where the rules are stored.

Comment: "I want to call file like this using htaccess" - You can't. (Only in the server config can you "include" other config files.) Why don't you simply copy the contents of `301.html` directly into your `.htaccess` file? "redirect about 50 links from one page to another" - I guess you don't really mean that these "50 link" are on "one page"?!